# Returning multiple view from spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to return multiple views(jsp) from one **controller**. i.e. one view below another

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "register")
public String addUser(Model model) {
    // on some condition
    if(){
     //add "user/login" above or below "user/edit"
    }
    model.addAttribute(new User());
    return "user/edit";
}
```

i want to do this on controller not on jsp

it can be possible or i have to use tiles for it

Answer (score 1):

You can only return one view. If you do not want to use a  templating library then you need to set some model attribute and then use that to conditionally render some additional HTML.

CONTROLLER

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "register")
public String addUser(Model model) {

    if(x){
        model.addAttribute("showAdditionalFields", true);
    }

    model.addAttribute(new User());

    return "user/edit";
}
```

JSP

```
<c:if test="${showAdditionalFields}">
    <!-- include here -->
</c:if>
```

Comment: that i have done. but does it not looking bad approach or looking view complicated.

Comment: templating library you mean spring tiles